# How do I get the locations that a flavor is supported in

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using URL  https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions?objectMask=mask[flavor.locations,flavor.locationCount]

The locations and the locationCount aren't returned. Can you help?   Thanks

Comment: this method not supported  with using masks

Answer (score 0):

try with this request

**Example**

```
https:\\api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/[packageId]/getActivePresets?objectMask=mask[locations,locationCount]
```

Public Virtual Server(packageId=835)

Public Virtual Server(packageId=1035)

Private and Dedicated Virtual Serve(packageId=46)

Transient Virtual Server(packageId=991)

You select the packageId that you want to get information about it.

Comment: Thank you! Can I also use this for Bare Metal active packages? How do I find the package IDs for Bare Metal?

Comment: for finding the package id, could you use this endpoint https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package_server/getAllObjects